# How to Change the command line macros in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, webots

I'm trying to create a Webots controller in VS2017 (through the webots software). When it loads up Visual Studio, everything is linked correctly and compiles correctly until I close VS and reopen it. Afterwards the macro of $(WEBOTS_HOME) changes to an incorrect path, which messes up the links to the files and libraries.

I tried to hard code the path in through properties editor, but it just says that all the files don't exist.

Links to error images:

[Correct Macro Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0xR9.jpg)

[Incorrect Macro + Correct Hard Coded Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QY1E9.jpg)

[Error From Hard Coded Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h17hp.jpg)

Is there any way to change what this macro evaluates as, or a way to keep it from changing in the first place? After spending a couple hours on the internet looking for answers, I've determined that I can't add a user macro, which was my idea to replace the broken macro, because I can't access "Project Manager" Tab, only a console version.

Comment: _When it loads up Visual Studio_ - what "it" are you referring to?  The Webots software?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm The "it" is the visual studio software that should be configured to work with the webots libraries.

Comment: WEBOTS_HOME is indeed supposed to be defined (typically WEBOTS_HOME=C:\Program Files\Webots). It can be defined in you user environment variables (https://superuser.com/questions/949560/how-do-i-set-system-environment-variables-in-windows-10). Doing this, it will be certainly accessible from VS.

Comment: @FabienRohrer That worked! Thank you!

Comment: Ok, I just post this as an answer (to be accepted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WEBOTS_HOME` environment variable is indeed supposed to be defined (for a typical Webots installation: `WEBOTS_HOME = C:\Program Files\Webots`). It can be defined in [your user environment variables](https://superuser.com/questions/949560/how-do-i-set-system-environment-variables-in-windows-10). Doing this, it will be accessible from VS.